# String format for Castle DictionaryAdapter

Tags: configuration, castle-windsor, app-config, configuration-files, castle-dictionaryadapter

I'm using Castle DictionaryAdapter in order to get the application settings from the **app.config** as an interface ( based on [Getting rid of strings (3): take your app settings to the next level](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/09/05/Getting-rid-of-strings-%283%29-take-your-app-settings-to-the-next-level.aspx) ):

```
public interface ISettings {
  int MaxUsers { get; }
  string FeedbackMail { get; }
  DateTime LastUserLogin { get; }
}
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MaxUsers" value="20"/>
    <add key="FeedbackMail" value="foo@localhost"/>
    <add key="LastUserLogin" value="2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to configure DictionaryAdapter to use a custom string format like **"yyyyMMdd-HHmm"** for converting the value stored in **app.config** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own TypeConverter and use it by applying the TypeConverter attribute.

See the [PhoneConverter sample in the tests](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core/blob/master/src/Castle.Core.Tests/Components.DictionaryAdapter.Tests/DictionaryAdapterFactoryTestCase.cs).